# TYPEOrm how to apply where LIKE on entity ID

Tags: postgresql, sql-like, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I'm using `TypeORM` on my application and I try to make a query filtered on multiple fields.
My entity look like this :

```
@Entity()
export default class Settings extends Base {
    @IsString()
    @IsDefined()
    @MaxLength(256)
    @MinLength(2)
    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 256 })
    public transport: string;

    @Type(() => Beneficiary)
    @OneToOne(() => Beneficiary, {
        nullable: false,
        eager: true,
    })
    @JoinColumn()
    public beneficiary: Beneficiary
}
```

I want to filter my query on `transport` field with operator LIKE.
And also want to filter my query on `beneficiary` with operator LIKE.

Here is my query :

```
const [settings, totalSettings] = await getRepository(Settings).findAndCount(
    {
        loadRelationIds: true,
        where: {
            transport: Like('%bike%'),
            beneficiary: Like('35'),
        },
    },
)
```

I used `loadRelationIds` to map the entity behind `beneficiary` to get the id directly rather than the complete object.
I saw that I can directly use the mapped field `beneficiary` like this in my where :

```
where: {
    transport: Like('%bike%'),
    beneficiary: '3',
},
```

But if I add the operator `Like` before, I got this error :

> QueryFailedError: operator does not exist: integer ~~ unknown

Is there a way to add the operator `LIKE` to this field ?

It's look like I can't use Like on number or entity data.
Or I badly written my query.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that I could think of was to use Raw typescript inside where option, so something like this:

```
where: {
    transport: Like('%bike%'),
    beneficiary: Raw((alias) => `CAST(${alias} as varchar) ILike '%${3}%'`)
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
return {
     ...this.createWithoutSearchCondition(memberId, isArchived),
     ...{
       [fieldName]: Raw(
         (alias) => `CAST(${alias} AS VARCHAR) ILike  :search`,
         {
           search: `%${search}%`,
         }
       ),
     },
   };
```